# PHPUnit stub method returning NULL?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to mock a singleton using [this method described by the author of PHPUnit](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/882-Testing-Code-That-Uses-Singletons.html) and stub one of its methods:

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->_foo = $this->getMockBuilder('Foo')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $this->_foo->expects($this->any())
        ->method('bar')
        ->will($this->returnValue('bar'));

    var_dump($this->_foo->bar());
}
```

The problem is that this dumps `NULL` every time.  As I understand it, when you mock an object, all the methods are replaced with stubs that return `NULL` unless explicitly stubbed like I'm doing.  So, since I've stubbed the `bar()` method, why is it not dumping the expected `'bar'` string?  What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a problem with my PHPUnit version.  I updated to the latest stable release, and was unable to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, for me the issue turned out to be that the method I was invoking didn't exist on the original object, and was being handled by `__call`. The solution ended up looking like:

```
$this->_foo->expects($this->any())
    ->method('__call')
    ->with($this->equalTo('bar'))
    ->will($this->returnValue('bar'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help, it's my entire replica of your problem. It prints out the desired 'bar'. I recommend checking that you are running the latest versions of phpunit and php i run:

PHPUnit 3.6.10 and PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.

```
$suite  = new PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite("TestTest");


class Foo {

    function Bar()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class TestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
    private $test_max_prod;
    private $initial;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->_foo = $this->getMockBuilder('Foo')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $this->_foo->expects($this->any())
            ->method('bar')
            ->will($this->returnValue('bar'));

        var_dump($this->_foo->bar());
    }

    function tearDown() {

    }

    function testTest(){}



}
```

Output

```
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.string(3) "bar"


Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

I hope this was helpful.